# How to import data to table on js?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm new on electron.js and also on web development. I want to add table items on index.js page, but I'm facing problems like in the pictures.

[image: 2]

Error code is:

> ts(2657)

Here is code:

```
const sideMenu = document.querySelector("aside");
const menuBtn = document.querySelector("#menu-btn");
const closeBtn = document.querySelector("#close-btn");
const themeToggler = document.querySelector(".theme-toggler");

// show sidebar
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    sideMenu.style.display = 'block';
})

// close sidebar
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    sideMenu.style.display = 'none';
})

// change theme
themeToggler.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme-variables');

    themeToggler.querySelector('span:nth-child(1)').classList.toggle('active');
    themeToggler.querySelector('span:nth-child(2)').classList.toggle('active');
})


// fill orders in table
Orders.forEach(order => {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    const trContent = 
    
                        '
                        <td>${order.productName}</td>
                        <td>${order.productNumber}</td>
                        <td>${order.paymentStatus}</td>
                        <td class="${order.shipping ===
                        'Declined' ? 'danger' : order.
                        'shipping' === 'pending' ? 'warning'
                        : 'primary'}">${order.shipping}</td>
                        <td class="primary">Details</td>
                        ';
    
})
```

Comment: Actually, I want to write insert

Comment: Are you using react? Error : `JSX expressions must have one parent element.ts(2657)`

Comment: Please post the code instead of the image

Comment: I want to make desktop app on electron.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert data as shown in the picture using pure text, first of all, you should use backticks (``); This allows you to interpolate data from variables and write multiline text.

After that, you might want to put that text inside the element of course. The code will look something like this:

```
const tr = document.createElement('tr');
const trContent = `
    <td>${order.productName}</td>
    <td>${order.productNumber}</td>
    <td>${order.paymentStatus}</td>
    <td class="${order.shipping === 'Declined' ? 'danger' : (order.shipping === 'pending' ? 'warning' : ' primary')}">
        ${order.shipping}
    </td>
    <td class="primary">Details</td>
`;

tr.innerHTML = trContent;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating OP's solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> I found the problem. After `const trContent=` I used the 1st key. But actually, I must use the 2nd key.
> [image]